# spring boot java UUID is not created for requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, uuid

I am programming a MicroService project and the last thing I wanted to do was to create an UUID for each request and I did this based on site https://medium.com/@d.lopez.j/spring-boot-setting-a-unique-id-per-request-dd648efef2b. The program runs but the ID is not created,Please help me solve the problem, thank you for your help.

===========================================================================

```
package first.app.microservice.uuid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.slf4filter")
public class Slf4jMDCFilterConfiguration {

    public static final String DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TOKEN_HEADER = "Response_Token";
    public static final String DEFAULT_MDC_UUID_TOKEN_KEY = "Slf4jMDCFilter.UUID";

    private String responseHeader = DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TOKEN_HEADER;
    private String mdcTokenKey = DEFAULT_MDC_UUID_TOKEN_KEY;
    private String requestHeader = null;



    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        final Slf4jMDCFilter log4jMDCFilterFilter = new Slf4jMDCFilter(responseHeader, mdcTokenKey, requestHeader);
        registrationBean.setFilter(log4jMDCFilterFilter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(2);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

=======================================================================

```
package first.app.microservice.uuid;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Component
public class Slf4jMDCFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final String responseHeader;
    private final String mdcTokenKey;
    private final String requestHeader;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
            throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            final String token;
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(requestHeader) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getHeader(requestHeader))) {
                token = request.getHeader(requestHeader);
            } else {
                token = UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase().replace("-", "");
            }
            MDC.put(mdcTokenKey, token);
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(responseHeader)) {
                response.addHeader(responseHeader, token);
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove(mdcTokenKey);
        }
    }
}
```

=======================================================
this is the controller of the project

```
package first.app.microservice.controller;


import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import first.app.microservice.MicroserviceApplication;
import first.app.microservice.mapstruct.Entities.OfficeDto;
import first.app.microservice.mapstruct.mappers.OfficeMapper;
import first.app.microservice.model.Office;
import first.app.microservice.service.OfficeService;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/office")
public class OfficeController {

    private OfficeService officeService;
    private OfficeMapper officeMapper;
    static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(MicroserviceApplication.class);




    @Autowired
    public OfficeController(OfficeService officeService, OfficeMapper officeMapper) {
        this.officeService = officeService;
        this.officeMapper = officeMapper;
    }



    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<OfficeDto> addOffice(@Valid @RequestBody OfficeDto officeDto){
        logger.info("Controller:Registering new Office  {}" ,officeDto.toString());
        Office office = officeService.register(officeMapper.officeDtoToOffice(officeDto));
        OfficeDto officeDto1  =  officeMapper.officeToOfficeDto(office);
        logger.info("Controller:Registering new Office  {}" ,officeDto1.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(officeDto1);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<OfficeDto>> all(){
        logger.info("Controller:Fetching All Offices.");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(officeMapper.officesToOfficesDto(officeService.findAll()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<OfficeDto> findById(@PathVariable Long id){
        Optional<Office> office = officeService.findById(id);
        OfficeDto officeDto = officeMapper.officeToOfficeDto(office.get());
        logger.info("Controller: Fetching user with id {}", id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(officeDto);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteById(@PathVariable Long id){
        logger.info("Controller: Finding user with id {}", id);
        officeService.deleteById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }


    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<OfficeDto> updateOffice(@PathVariable Long id , @RequestBody OfficeDto officeDto){
        logger.info("Controller:Sending new Office and Fetching Office with id {}", id);
        Office office = officeMapper.officeDtoToOffice(officeDto);
        Office office1 = officeService.updateById(id,office);
        OfficeDto officeDto1 = officeMapper.officeToOfficeDto(office1);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(officeDto1 , HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

===============================================
this is the application.properties for logging

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.guru.springframework.controllers=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=debug
logging.file.name=logs/archived/MICRO_LOG.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern=logs/archived/MICRO_LOG.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=10MB
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.total-size-cap=20GB
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=7
```

============================================================

### https://github.com/GHT1212/OfficeMicroservice/tree/master/src/main/java/first/app/microservice

### https://github.com/GHT1212/OfficeMicroservice/blob/master/src/main/java/first/app/microservice/uuid/Slf4jMDCFilter.java

### https://github.com/GHT1212/OfficeMicroservice/blob/master/src/main/java/first/app/microservice/uuid/Slf4jMDCFilterConfiguration.java

here is the project repository link.

Comment: Remove `@Component` from the filter, the fact that the tutorial mentions that (or does it like this) makes me wonder about the whole tutorial...

Comment: Have you considered using Spring Cloud Sleuth instead of doing this on your own?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.